# How to deliberately generate error in PhP

Tags: php, exception

Is there a command for that? Throw exception, error or anything?

That way not only my PhP program will crash it will jot down something on error log.

Comment: What error log? How is this related to Objective-C or Xcode?

Comment: How about [this](http://php.net/exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [trigger_error()](https://www.php.net/trigger_error), which has the following signature:

```
bool trigger_error ( string $error_msg [, int $error_type = E_USER_NOTICE ] )
```

Alternatively, you can use the [throw](https://www.php.net/throw) keyword to throw an instance of the default Exception class:

```
throw new Exception( string $error_msg )
```